# 2 sequences whose product tends to infinity with $\liminf$ condition

Tags: real-analysis

Here is one question from my homework. I come out the answer based on some hints from other websites, but I'm confused with one step.

Prove that

if $\lim(s_n)= +\infty$ and $\liminf(t_n) > 0$, then $\lim(s_nt_n)= +\infty$.

The process I have right now:
Set lim inf tn = A ==> |tn|<A for all n.
Let B in R, since limsn = +infinity, there exist N0 in R such that all n in N, n>N0, sn > B/A * A = B => all n in R, exist N in R, all n in N, |sntn|>B ==> lim(sntn)=+infinity

My question is:

1. Why lim inf tn = M means |tn|<M? from my perspective, lim inf tn would be the greatest number in the sequence (tn) which is less than or equal to every number in the sequence. In this situation, isn't we need to say |tn|>M?
2. Why can we set sn > B/A * A here?

If the proof above doesn't make sense, could someone help? Thank you very much for your thinking and time~

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think you should dump that proof. It has too many mistakes.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title which wasn't a title... Inspect as well the Latex way of writing things.

Answer (score 1):

The following paragraph is full of mistakes:

Set $\lim \inf t_n = A \implies |t_n|<A$ for all $n$.
Let $B$ in $R$, since $\lim s_n = \infty$, there exist $N_0$ in $R$ such that all $n \in \mathbb N, n>N_0$, $s_n > B/A * A = B$ which implies all $n$ in $R$, there exists $N \in R$, all $n \in \mathbb N$, $|s_nt_n|>B$ which implies $\lim(s_nt_nn)=\infty$

Here is a valid proof: With $A$ defined as above there exists $N_0$ such that $t_n >\frac  A 2$ for $n >N_0$.
Given any positive number $M$ we can choose $N_1$ such that $s_n >\frac {2M} A
$ for $n >N_1$. If $n >\max \{N_0,N_1\}$ then $t_ns_n > \frac A 2\frac {2M} A=M$.